# Make javafx choicebox select item based on keyboard

Tags: java, javafx

According to https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/ChoiceBox+User+Experience+Documentation

`Any Alpha-numeric Keys` should  `Jumps to the first item in the list with that letter or letters` in the `Selected state`

However, this doesn't seem to be the case at all, typing when the widget is selected does not appear to do anything.

Here is my minimal reproducible example:

```java
package com.techniqab.testchoicebox;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class TestchoiceboxApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        URL url = Paths.get("./src/main/resources/sample.fxml").toUri().toURL();

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

        var cb = new ChoiceBox();
        cb.getItems().add("a");
        cb.getItems().add("b");

        ((Pane) root).getChildren().add(cb);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="com.techniqab.testchoicebox.TestchoiceboxApplication"
            prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">

</AnchorPane>
```

```
module testchoicebox {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    exports com.techniqab.testchoicebox;
    opens com.techniqab.testchoicebox to javafx.graphics;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [mre]: this relies on an FXML file you haven't posted. (And, off-topic, but why are you loading the FXML file from the source folder?)

Comment: The feature is marked `Application Dependant` [_sic_], which perhaps means that it's up to your application.

Comment: @trashgod I don't see where it is marked as Application Dependent...my application depends on this, how do I make it happen

Comment: @James_D added the other files...as to the FXML.. location because I'm new to java/spring/and javafx and that's how I figured out to get a minimum example running.

Comment: Two use cases are marked `Dependant`—note the misspelling. For a long list, maybe some kind of `Pagination` control?

Comment: @trashgod It looks to me like the "Application Depandant" note is about when the node is not focused "Pointer off button".

Comment: @Techniquab: Ah, I read the section cited as [_normative_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativity), rather than dispositive of existing functionality.

Comment: @trashgod well now you've gone and used words I don't understand and I pride myself on my vocab. Nice work.

Comment: @Techniquab: My reading may be off, but the [specification](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/User+Experience+Specifications) says, "UX specifications cover the _expected_ functionality of a UI control…" In this case, if you add support for "Any Alpha-numeric Keys," the effect should be "Jumps to the first item in the list with that letter or letters."

Comment: @trashgod ok...well then I guess I've gone and figured out how to make it do what it seemed like it should have done all along,

Comment: FWIW, there is the same issue with the [ComboBox user experience documentation](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/ComboBox+User+Experience+Documentation), which states under the Keyboard Support section "Any Key: Move the selection to the item matching prefix letters.", however, this processing of any key is not to change selection is not implemented for ComboBoxes in JavaFX 17.

Comment: @jewelsea: Multi-key prefix alternatives for both `ComboBox` and `ChoiceBox` are include in _ControlsFX_.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it reinvents something that should work...and obviously one would want to subclass the ChoiceBox and add this behavior rather than the hack i've done here as a POC... but this works

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalTime;


public class TestchoiceboxApplication extends Application {
    private String typed="";
    private Boolean gotIt=false;
    private Instant lastKeyTime = Instant.now();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        URL url = Paths.get("./src/main/resources/sample.fxml").toUri().toURL();

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

        var cb = new ChoiceBox();
        cb.getItems().add("a");
        cb.getItems().add("b");
        cb.getItems().add("ab");
        cb.getItems().add("aa");
        cb.getItems().add("c");
        cb.getItems().add("cba");


        EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler =
                new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                    public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.UNDEFINED) {
                            return;
                        }
                        keyEvent.consume();

                        var  now = Instant.now();
                        if (Duration.between(lastKeyTime, now).getSeconds()>3) {
                            //reset search after timeout
                            typed="";
                        }
                        lastKeyTime = now;

                        typed = typed + keyEvent.getCharacter();
                        var items = cb.getItems();
                        int nMatch = 0;
                        int i=0;
                        for (var item: items) {
                            if (item.toString().startsWith(typed)) {
                                if (nMatch==0) {
                                    cb.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                                }
                                nMatch++;
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (nMatch>1) {
                            cb.show();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            if (nMatch == 1) {
                                cb.hide();
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        // key didn't match
                        typed =  keyEvent.getCharacter();
                        cb.show();
                        nMatch = 0;
                        for (var item: items) {
                            if (item.toString().startsWith(typed)) {
                                if (nMatch==0) {
                                    cb.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                                }
                                nMatch++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (nMatch>1) {
                            cb.show();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            if (nMatch == 1) {
                                cb.hide();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        typed = "";
                    };
                };

        cb.setOnKeyTyped(keyEventHandler);
        ((Pane) root).getChildren().add(cb);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to get the enter or return key to accept the selection; I have to click the mouse. Does your sample.fxml influence this?

Comment: @trashgod looks like you can only get the KeyCode in the KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED / KEY_RELEASED handlers https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCode() we need to check for '\r' || '\n' or handle the pressed/released seperately

Comment: Ah, I see the meaning of `KeyCode.UNDEFINED`, now. You're using higher-level _key typed_ events, while my [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69592353/230513) mixes _key typed_ with the _lower-level_ events. I'm still trying to understand the _ControlsFX_ cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69592353/230513)

Comment: @trashgod I noticed an other issue, the selection will move as I expect and display a checkbox on the selected item, but if my mouse is in the list, the updown arrows will work with respect to the last item the mouse hovered over rather than the last selection.

Comment: The _ControlsFX_ implementation is [here](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx/blob/jfx-13/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/tools/PrefixSelectionCustomizer.java) if you go that route.

Answer (score 1):

While the [*ChoiceBox User Experience Documentation*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/ChoiceBox+User+Experience+Documentation) is normative, this simpler variation jumps to the first item in the list having the letter typed. It also responds to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd> keys.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/69591397/230513
 */
public class KeyTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Key Test");
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "a10", "b42", "c33", "a11", "b22", "c333", "d0");
        FXCollections.sort(items);
        ChoiceBox cb = new ChoiceBox(items);
        EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler = (var e) -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                return;
            }
            e.consume();
            for (var item : cb.getItems()) {
                if (item.toString().startsWith(e.getCharacter())) {
                    cb.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                    cb.show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        cb.setOnKeyTyped(keyEventHandler);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        StackPane.setMargin(cb, new Insets(16, 16, 16, 16));
        root.getChildren().add(cb);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

For multi-key *prefix* selection, as described [here](http://www.kware.net/?p=233), also consider [`PrefixSelectionChoiceBox`](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.1.0/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/PrefixSelectionChoiceBox.html) or [`PrefixSelectionComboBox`](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.1.0/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/PrefixSelectionComboBox.html) included in [*ControlsFX*](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx#controlsfx).